# How do i center align text in different screen sizes

Tags: html, jquery, css, fonts

[image]

Like shown in the image, the highlighted text is not in the center when i lower the screen size.

My both `css` and `html` code are here:

`css`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  src: url("Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf") format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'descFont';
  src: url("Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
}

html { overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x:hidden; }
body { position: absolute; }

.container {
  /* height: 90vh; */
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: sticky;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #181818;
  padding: 8px 25px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.main {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  /* font-size: 5.6vw; */
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #181818;
}

.subMain {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  /* font-size: 3.5vw; */
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #313131;
  position: absolute;
}

.pfp {
  max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

.description {
  font-family: 'descFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  /* font-size: 1.75vw; */
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #373737;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -80px;
  text-align: left;
}

.typed-text {
  color: chartreuse;
}

.cursor {
  animation: blinker 0.6s linear infinite;
  color: #181818; 
}

.space {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.container p span.typed-text {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  color: #181818;
}

.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.cursor.typing {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}

h2, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* div {
  vertical-align: bottom;
} */
```

`html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <title>Saharsh</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
    </head>
    <body class='container'>
        <div>
            <nav class='navbar'>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>

            <img class='pfp' src='Images/pfp.png' style='height:150px; border-radius: 50%; border: 10px solid chartreuse;'>

            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>

            <h1 class='main'>Hello , I'm Saharsh</h1>
            <h1 class='subMain'>and am a <span class="typed-text"></span><span class='cursor'></span></h1>

            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
            <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>

            <h1 class='description' style='text-align: center;'>more coming soon...</h1>
        </div>
        <script src='Scripts/I am a.js'> </script>
        <!-- <script src='Scripts/Say Hello.js'> </script> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe it's because of `position: absolute;` but hard to tell when we can't debug it

Comment: so what should i change `position: absolute;` to?

Comment: First I don't understand why you use position absolute in the first place. Second use Media queries to detect the width and remove the position absolute inside that

Comment: alright, i'll use media queries, thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I said in comment you can use `media queries` to detect the "size" of the screen and change the css according to requirement.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .subMain{position:inherit}
}
```

Note: It would be more correct to do this:

```
.subMain {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  /* font-size: 3.5vw; */
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #313131;
  position:absolute; <--- remove this
  text-align: left; <--- add this
}
```

and now inside your media query do

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .subMain{text-align:center;}
}
```

**Demo**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  src: url("Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf") format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'descFont';
  src: url("Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  /* height: 90vh; */
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: sticky;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #181818;
  padding: 8px 25px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.main {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  /* font-size: 5.6vw; */
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #181818;
}

.subMain {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  /* font-size: 3.5vw; */
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #313131;
  position: absolute;
}

.pfp {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
  /* ie8 */
}

.description {
  font-family: 'descFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  /* font-size: 1.75vw; */
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #373737;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -80px;
  text-align: left;
}

.typed-text {
  color: chartreuse;
}

.cursor {
  animation: blinker 0.6s linear infinite;
  color: #181818;
}

.space {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.container p span.typed-text {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  color: #181818;
}

.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.cursor.typing {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

h2,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


/* div {
  vertical-align: bottom;
} */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .subMain{position:inherit}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Saharsh</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body class='container'>
  <div>
    <nav class='navbar'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>About me</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>

    <img class='pfp' src='Images/pfp.png' style='height:150px; border-radius: 50%; border: 10px solid chartreuse;'>

    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>

    <h1 class='main'>Hello , I'm Saharsh</h1>
    <h1 class='subMain'>and am a <span class="typed-text"></span><span class='cursor'></span></h1>

    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>
    <br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'><br class='unselectable'>

    <h1 class='description' style='text-align: center;'>more coming soon...</h1>
  </div>
  <script src='Scripts/I am a.js'>
  </script>
  <!-- <script src='Scripts/Say Hello.js'> </script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, i had to change the `max-width:  600px` to `max-width:  828px` which was  the maximum width

Comment: And now everything just works perfectly!

Comment: @Saharsh thats fine, 600 was just a guess from my side.